# iOS 8 download keeps timing out

Tags: ios

I have the 32 GB iPhone 5s.  I have 19 GB remaining in my iCloud space.

It was suggested to use my laptop to download iOS 8.0 and update my phone via iTunes but it keeps telling me the internet connection timed out.

Is this happening because Apple's update site is overwhelmed, perhaps?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error you are getting on the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have been experiencing this, too. And no dice on using the device to update, either. It has to be on Apple's end, though. There are intermittent reports of this timeout all over the country. My guess is to wait 'til the hubbub has subsided and then leech away! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues downloading IOS updates via my Mac.

One thing I found that, surprisingly, seems to work well is to not update via your Mac (or PC) rather download the update on your iPhone (on WiFi of course).

For whatever reason these update come down faster and more reliably, at least for me.

Standard rules apply, be sure you are on WiFi and that your Phone is showing 100% charge before starting the update. And finally back up your iPhone immediately before applying the update.